# get data form database & display in gridview's textboxes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-part, javascript, asp.net

i want to populate data in gridview's textboxes which are stored in database and if no value found in database it should show blank text boxes.
[image]

BUT my problem is i am binding gridview data for Area & parameter on page load is coming from table "A" and after that if user save any values in textboxes it will be stored in table"B"(only those rows values will be stored for which the checkbox is checked). and after that when the page load will take place,i want to show those values in textboxes(from Table "B"), and if no value found in database it should show blank text boxes for that row.

Comment: If you know how to do it on ASP.NET, you should know how to do it in a SharePoint Web Part..

Comment: no i am trying in asp.net.but it's not working